# giving this error when I am using assets in flutter vs code assets: - assets/images/

Tags: flutter

giving this error when I am using assets in flutter vs code assets: - assets/images/

```
[demo] flutter pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 51, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
   ╷
51 │    assets:
   │    ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at D:\Flutter\demo\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1
```

Comment: Give me screenshot of  pubspec.yaml ,

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml file screenshot or code

It looks like you haven't added new line after `assets:`

Comment: assets:
   - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your there is some syntax error in your pubspec.yaml file.

Below is a snippet as to how the assets part is supposed to be mentioned in the pubspec.yaml file.

```
flutter:
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   assets:
    - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
    - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Now the images folder needs to be placed in your main directory and not inside lib folder.

Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pubspec.yaml is case sensitive and it needs care regarding spacing.

no space to parent
2 space to child
2 more space to grand child

Hope it makes you understood

Comment: assets:
   - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg